# How can i set image view on the web view and center of the webview?

Tags: android

I'm beginner in android,i want write some xml code for design this:
[image]

i write this code for that purpose:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/newit" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:paddingStart="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

but dont work to me,how can i implant that?thanks.

Comment: declare the `ImageView` below `WebView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:paddingStart="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/newit" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Glad i could help you out :)